# vorticity flux conservation for NS equation in 2D

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Can someone explain to me why the vorticity flux is conserved for a solution to navier stokes equation in 2D ?
Ie why $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} w(x,t) dx =cst$ if $w$ satisfy the vorticity equation for navier stokes system:
$\frac{d}{dt}w + (v\cdot \nabla) w = (w\cdot \nabla)v + \Delta w$ with $v$ divergence free.

If one integrate the equation then he gets $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} w dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \Delta w dx$ the right hand side should not be necessarily zero am I right ?

Comment: If we are assuming that $w(x,t) \to 0$ is $x\to\infty$ (and that is needed to make sense of the first integral), then just use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Is the following what you are saying : 
$\int_{B(0,R)} \Delta wdx = \int_{B(0,R)} div(\nabla w)dx=\int_{\partial B(0,R)} \nabla w dx$ but then how the hypothesis $|w(.,t)| \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ would imply that $|\nabla w(.,t)| \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. I don't think it is true.

Comment: Ok is this how we justify everything:
We assume that $w$ is smooth, but then if we want to integrate it and its first order and second order derivatives we must also assume that they vanish in absolute value as $x\to \infty$ ?

Comment: Something like that.  I didn't think you were trying to be rigorous.  It could be made rigorous, but then you need to state more hypotheses, and you need to quote (or prove) results about how solutions to the 2D N-S behaves.

Comment: Would this clean statement be correct :

Let $(v,p)$ be a smooth solution to NS 2D in $[0;T)$, and suppose its vorticity and its derivatives decays as $|x|^{-2}$, Then the vorticity flux is conserved: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}w(x,t)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} w_0(x)dx$ for any $t \in [0;T)$

Comment: I think that should work.  Except if $w$ only decays like $|x|^{-2}$, I don't see how you can be sure that $\int_{\mathbb R^2} w(x,t) \, dx$ is well defined.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, it should decay at least as $|x|^{-3}$ thank you !